# Word order in 犬のホワイトチョコレート

Tags: grammar, particle-の

Some time ago I was speaking with a Japanese teacher, and to say "A white chocolate dog" she said `犬のホワイトチョコレート`; I asked, shouldn't it be `ホワイトチョコレートの犬`, since `犬のホワイトチョコレート` sounded to me like "A white chocolate of dog" or "Dog's white chocolate", but she confirmed `犬` first. I was unable to understand why `犬` goes as first element, though, I think something about `犬` being the main concept. Any ideas?

If it does is `犬のホワイトチョコレート`, how do you understand if something like `男のホワイトチョコレート` means "A man's white chocolate" or "A man of white chocolate"?

Edit: the meaning was - and it was clear for both the teacher and me - a edible dog made out of white chocolate; there was no misunderstading about that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The particle の has many roles.

犬のホワイトチョコレート can potentially mean:

1. a dog named White Chocolate (compare トナカイのルドルフ "Rudolph the reindeer" and 友達のジョン "my friend John")
2. dog-shaped white chocolate
3. white chocolate owned by a certain dog
4. white chocolate made specially for dogs

ホワイトチョコレートの犬 can potentially mean:

1. an edible dog made of white chocolate
2. a (living) dog that is somehow like white chocolate
3. a dog owned by a person called White Chocolate
4. a dog born in a place called White Chocolate

I feel "a white chocolate dog" is a little confusing. Maybe she took it as "a dog called White Chocolate" but you meant an edible dog? If you explain it in other words, you may get a different response from her.

As for 男のホワイトチョコレート, I probably take it as "special white chocolate for men" if there is no context, but it's equally ambiguous.

**EDIT:** If the intended meaning is "an (edible) dog made of white chocolate", both 犬のホワイトチョコレート and ホワイトチョコレートの犬 can potentially refer to that, but the former is like "dog(-shaped) chocolate" whereas the latter is like "chocolate(-made) dog". The final noun is the main noun. Anyway, you should avoid ambiguous phrases like these unless there is clear context. Usually it's much better to say 犬の形のチョコレート or チョコレートでできた犬.

Comment: I edited the original question to clarify: the meaning was - and it was clear for both the teacher and me - a edible dog made out of white chocolate; there was no misunderstading about that.


If both `犬のホワイトチョコレート` and `ホワイトチョコレートの犬` could mean a dog made of white chocolate, there is any nuance? Do you have any idea why she preferred the former? To say dog-shaped white chocolate I'd have used the latter.

Comment: @Mauro The final noun is the "main" noun, so 犬のチョコレート is "dog(-shaped) chocolate" and チョコレートの犬 is "a chocolate(-made) dog". Anyway, you should avoid ambiguous phrases like this unless there is clear context. It's much better to say 犬の形のチョコレート or チョコレートでできた犬.

Comment: I think that's what the teacher meant while trying to explain, guess I just have to get used to it, thanks. I accepted your answer, could you edit it with your last comment? I think it'd be very useful to have it in the answer's main body.

Comment: Yes, while the whole answer body is useful, I also think the question is actually answered in your further comment.